# Adaptive regression splines in earth package R

Tags: r

I am using earth package for the following data.

```
x <- c(127, 128, 255, 256, 511, 512, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1023, 1100,
       1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 2047, 2048, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500,
       2600, 2700, 2800, 3000, 3100, 3200, 3300, 3500, 4063, 4064, 4100, 4200,
       5200, 5400)

y <- c(0.59, 0.61, 0.59, 1.55, 1.33, 3.50, 1.00, 1.22, 2.50, 3.00, 3.79,
       3.98, 4.33, 4.45, 4.59, 4.72, 4.82, 4.90, 4.96, 7.92, 5.01, 5.01,
       4.94, 5.05, 5.04, 5.03, 5.06, 5.10, 5.04, 5.06, 7.77, 5.07, 5.08,
       5.08, 5.12, 5.12, 5.08, 5.17, 5.18)
```

After building the model,

```
model<-earth(y~x)
```

I get following regression model.

```
summary(model)
Call: earth(x=x, y=y)
coefficients
(Intercept)  5.225822553
h(1400-x)   -0.003820087
```

Is there any possibility that I can increase somehow the number of knots or regression splines?

Comment: I believe that the MARS/Earth algorithm used in the earth package does not let the user set the number of splines because the whole point of the [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_adaptive_regression_splines) is to choose the number of splines endogenously. You do have control over [`nk` and `nprune`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/earth/vignettes/earth-notes.pdf) though.

Comment: Yes, try the `gam()` function in package **mgcv** which ships with all versions of R. There are others too but that or the **gam** package would be most similar in spirit to what MARS is doing in this univariate case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there could be several ways. First notice that the model selected is the one with minimal GCV of those fitted. Hence the algorithm has pruned out additional terms as they contribute little to the fit yet add complexity to the model. The issue here is one of parsimony and trying to avoid overfitting.

As the model is selected by GCV we can choose the penalty per term in the GCV computation and indeed, setting this to `-1` results in a model where the GCV criterion is in effect the RSS/`n` where `n` is the number of terms.

```
> model <- earth(y~x, penalty = -1)
> summary(model)
Call: earth(formula=y~x, penalty=-1)

            coefficients
(Intercept)    4.8340954
h(x-1400)      0.0014362
h(1400-x)     -0.0033889
h(x-2047)     -0.0027031
h(x-2500)      0.0012920

Selected 5 of 5 terms, and 1 of 1 predictors 
Importance: x
Number of terms at each degree of interaction: 1 4 (additive model)
GCV 0.5231077    RSS 20.4012    GRSq 0.8307609    RSq 0.8307609
```

We can see that this model has retained all 5 terms the were added to the spline pool during the initialisation of the forward pass. Note also that the addition of three more terms has only reduced the RSS by ~2 units, or about 10% of the RSS for the simpler model.

The other arguments of interest here are `nk` and `nprune` but neither seemed to have an effect on the resulting model for this sample of data.

Comment: @Simpson Gavin What about any other package(s) that would provide the possibility to control the number of knots. I used freeknotsplines packages but thats not what we want. I want the algorithm to partition the data and provide the linear regression spline model for each segment.

Comment: You want a local linear model? In that case try the **sm** package, which too is highly regarded and written by two eminent statisticians in the area of local models. If you were to relax the local linear assumption, try either of the packages I mentioned in the comment on Ari's Answer. Also, do consider Accepting Answers on Questions you ask (you have a low accept rate). See the [ask] section of the FAQ for why this is a good thing, and also how to accept (click the big tick mark next to an Answer).

Comment: There is also the **locfit** package which I believe can fit local linear models.

Comment: @Simpson Gavin Thanks alot. I tried alot with mgcv package but couldn't make a plot out of my data. Is it possible that you can provide me some steps (relevant to my data) in order to produce a fit for my data. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Ask a new question with an example and I, and others will take a look at it. It is difficult to say what is going on without code/example. Do note that you asked for a local linear model in a subsequent comment and **mgcv** won't give you that. You will get more enthusiasm for additional help if you accept more Answers though. I would have thought you could have Accepted either Ari's or mine given their content, yet you have not done so?

Comment: @Simpson Gavin Its not like that Mr. Gavin. I admire your explanation and I love the way you explain things. I am sorry for that I didn't accepted the answer yet but I did it just now. Thanks again.

Comment: @Simpson Gavin Thanks alot. I created one plot with sm package with the actual data and using the following function call.

`model<-sm.regression(x,y)`

and the graph looks good. But how can I predict new value for any given value of x with the help of this model? Thanks again.

Comment: Again, ask a new Question. It is difficult to Answer things nicely in comments as they lack the ability to format an Answer appropriately. If you ask a new Question I will take a look then.

Comment: Having had a quick look, I'm not sure you can generate predictions. So do ask a new Question to see what inputs other have.